# Fullcalendar dynamic data parameter and elaborate response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) with events retrieved by `ajax` call. The URL has a dynamic parameter that is the room id because I would like to show the calendar based on room choice. I have two problems:

1. `events` is called before the user can choose the room (room selection and calendar is loaded at the same time), so the `ajax` URL is not valid because there isn't the `room id`. Is it possible to avoid the first loading?
2. The `ajax` response is in a particolar format like this:

   ```
   {
     "status":true,"success":true,"result":
   [
     {
        "id":2,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-06T10:30:00","end":"2017-07-06T11:30:00"
     },
     {
       "id":3,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-07T16:30:00","end":"2017-07-07T17:30:00"
     }
    ],
   "error":null
   }
   ```

so I have to use only `result` field but `eventDataTransform` doesn't work with a JSON different from `event` format. Do you know if is it possible to elaborate the response before using it for the event?(I also use status and error to show message)
This is my actual code:

```
     var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        selectOverlap: false,
        height: 600,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaDay'
        },
        slotMinutes: 30,
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        maxTime: '18:00:00',
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: true,
        weekends: false,
        //this allow the click on month agenda and go to day agenda
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            if(view.name == 'month') {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);      
            }
        },
         eventDataTransform: function(eventData){
                   return eventData.result;
               },
        //load room reservation
        events: {
            url: '/booking/reservation/',
            data: function () { // a function that returns an object
                return {
                    idRoom: bookingForm.room,
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

bookingForm.room is loaded on `select` event:

```
roomTable.off('select')
    .on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
        bookingForm.room = roomTable.rows( indexes ).data().toArray()[0].idRoom;
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
    } );
```

Comment: Where is `bookingForm.room` currently defined?

Comment: sorry I updated the main post

Comment: "It is possibile to avoid the first loading?" Sure, just don't initialise the calendar at all until the user has chosen a room for the first time. Or, set a default room ID and just use that for the first loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with [Fullcalendar events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) where I can elaborate each single event field. This is my final code

```
success: function(doc) {
    if (doc.status && doc.success && bookingForm.room){
        var events = [];
        var color = [];
        for (index = 0; index < doc.result.length; ++index) {
            //change the color if user is the owner of event
            if (doc.result[index].owner == document.getElementById('username').innerHTML)
                color = '#3c8dbc';
            else 
                color = '#FF0000';
            events.push({
                editable: false,
                id: doc.result[index].id,
                title: doc.result[index].title,
                start: doc.result[index].start, 
                end: doc.result[index].end,
                color: color,
            });
        }
        callback(events);
    }
}
```

instead the first call to web service has done with a roomId initialize with -1 so it return no result

Answer (score 1):

> It is possibile to avoid the first loading?

Sure, simply don't set the `events` property and load the events later with [addEventSource](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/)

See following example please:

```js
var source = 
    [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2017-07-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2017-07-05',
            end    : '2017-07-07'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2017-08-09T12:30:00',
            allDay : false
        }
    ];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar();
});

$("#btnLoadEvents").click(function(){
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", source);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.print.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnLoadEvents">Load events</button>
<div id="calendar" />
```

> Do you know if is it possible to elaborate the response before use it for the event?

Yes, get the events from your custom ajax response:

```
var customAjaxResponse = {"status":true,"success":true,"result":[{"id":2,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-06T10:30:00","end":"2017-07-06T11:30:00"},{"id":3,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-07T16:30:00","end":"2017-07-07T17:30:00"}],"error":null};
var source = customAjaxResponse.result;
```

Then add the source to the calendar:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", source);
```

See the final result:

```js
var customAjaxResponse = {"status":true,"success":true,"result":[{"id":2,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-06T10:30:00","end":"2017-07-06T11:30:00"},{"id":3,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-07T16:30:00","end":"2017-07-07T17:30:00"}],"error":null};

var source = customAjaxResponse.result;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar();
});

$("#btnLoadEvents").click(function(){
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", source);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.print.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnLoadEvents">Load events</button>
<div id="calendar" />
```

**Note:** You could add events dynamically whenever you want, although other events are already present on the calendar (try to click many times on the buttons in the above example).

I hope it helps you, ciao Luca.

**Updated**: How to hide/show events with a specific filter:

For each single event you can check whether it's to be displayed or not, with a function on eventRender, like following:

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    var roomId = getRoomIdFromEvent(event.id);
    return $("#chkRoom" + roomId).is(':checked');
},
```

So, when the function returns true the event will be displayed otherwise it will be hidden.

Finally, when the filters change you have to refresh the calendar:

```
$(mySelector).click(function(){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
};
```

See following please:

```js
var customAjaxResponse = {"status":true,"success":true,"result":[{"id":2,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-06T10:30:00","end":"2017-07-06T11:30:00", "room": 1},{"id":3,"title":"test","start":"2017-07-07T16:30:00","end":"2017-07-07T17:30:00", "room": 2}],"error":null};

var source = customAjaxResponse.result;



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
      eventRender: function (ev, el, v) {
      console.log(ev);
        var roomId = ev.room;
        return $("#cmdRoom").val()==roomId;
    }
  });
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", source);
});

$("#cmdRoom").change(function(){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.print.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<select id="cmdRoom">
<option value="1">Room one</option>
<option value="2">Room two</option>
</select>
<div id="calendar" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I should delete and load data every time user click on room, is it right? But so does fullcalendar still trigger when the user clicks prev/next or switches views?It authomatically adds start date and end date as query param

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you need... please take a look to my updated answer (**Updated:** How to hide/show events with a specific filter). You can load all the events on loading and show/hide the events with a specific filter.